# Sorry to be a pain, but another 1064 error in MySQL 5.1.36

Tags: mysql, insert

error msg:

**1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'), values('name','url' at line 3**

create table:

```
create table lawyer_info
(firm_name varchar(100) not null,
firm_url varchar(100) not null,
firm_address varchar(100) not null,
firm_city varchar(100) not null,
firm_state varchar(100) not null,
firm_zip varchar(12) not null,
firm_phone varchar(15) not null);
```

data:

```
insert into lawyer_info firm_name,firm_url,firm_address,firm_city,firm_state,firm_zip,firm_phone)
values('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
values('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
values('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
values('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
values('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
values('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
values('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone');
```

Comment: Learn to read your errors, at least. Maybe then you won't have to feel as bad about coming back and posting so many questions, because by fixing them on your own you'll do so less.

Comment: Also, three "too localized" votes? Why? I get the collective frustration that OP hasn't made any apparent effort to do anything about the error, but I don't recall "too localized" being synonymous with "fix it yourself".

Comment: @Adam: I'm calm, but I figure some of the 11 people, as well as the three downvoters, aren't too pleased. The "too localized" votes I'm talking about are to the people who want to close your question for I-don't-know-what.

Comment: @BoltClock description of "too localized" says "an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet." . This is the case - the code is specific to the OP and not of much interest to wide audience (which SO targets if I read the rules right).

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp: What if someone else encounters the same error for a similar SQL query?

Comment: @BoltClock he will have to open MySQL manual and study, I guess.

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp: I think that a typo it's not a real question more than a localized question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL's bulk insert syntax doesn't require VALUES every time:

```
INSERT INTO lawyer_info 
  (firm_name,firm_url,firm_address,firm_city,firm_state,firm_zip,firm_phone)
VALUES ('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
       ('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
       ('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
       ('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
       ('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
       ('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
       ('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone');
```

Comment: The error lies with the missing `(` but you covered both cases anyway +1

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to wrap your column list in ( and as already mentioned remove the unnecessary values keyword.
Try this:

```
insert into lawyer_info (firm_name,firm_url,firm_address,firm_city,firm_state,firm_zip,firm_phone) 
values('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'), 
('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'), 
('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'), 
('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'), 
('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'), 
('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone');
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to name the columns.  Just:

```
insert into lawyer_info
values('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
      ('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone');
```

Comment: Nothing syntactically wrong with naming the columns.

Comment: And it's not a bad habit to get into, naming the columns, for that inevitable situation in which you don't want to insert a value into every column of a table in their declared order... :)